# Remote Web Inspector in Xcode iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, remote-debugging

I know with iOS6 it is possible to use remote web inspector by connecting the iOS6 device to MAC machine PC.

My Question here is: it is possible to use remote web inspector from XCode 4.x Simulator which also emulates the iOS6 devices?

Answer (score 1):

Use http://www.iwebinspector.com/.... Only works on iOS Simulator (not real devices) but it does the trick after all...